# Python recursive function recurSum(x, y)

Tags: recursion

This is my code:

```
def recurSum(x, y):
    if x <= 1:
        return x
    return x + recurSum(x - 1)
    if y <= 1:
        return y
```

xxwjhefbhwjbfwjh efjehwbf ebrfe
print(recurSum(5, 10))

Comment: Here is your recursive rule: `sum(x,y) = x + sum(x-1, y)` for `x>1` and `sum(1, y)=y+1`. Now just implement it.

Comment: @trincot `Sum(x, y) = y + 1+2+3+4+...+x` - this is how I understand it.

Comment: Unless this is an exercise in learning about recursion, you should't be *using* recursion. `return y + sum(range(x+1))`.

Comment: @trincot As Eugene said my aim is to reach Sum(x, y) = y + 1+2+3+4+...+x but I messed up the (5, 10), I wasnt sure what I was doing..

Comment: OK, so why not `y + recurSum(x)`, where `recurSum(x)` will just do what this function originally seem to have been doing?

Comment: @EugeneSh. can you please explain where I should put the sum (1, y) = y+1 into my code? shuld it be in the def or outside?

Comment: @sadasi78 This is the base case (terminating condition). Your code should have two branches - for `x > 1` and for `x==1`

Comment: @chepner Well, one could do `y+x*(x-1)//2` and go have a coffee :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Depends on how you interpret the problem being assigned :) Computationally, there's a difference between "add up the numbers" and "compute the sum", even if they are mathematically the same.

Comment: You should not edit the question with a "solution". It is a question and should remain such

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```py
def recurSum(x, y):
    if x==0:
        return y
    
    return recurSum(x - 1, y) + x
```

In essence, the base case is when the first number has reached 0. If so, you return the other number. Otherwise, you perform once again the recursive sum.

Comment: @chepner, I didn't get your suggestion, and you actually deleted it.

Comment: Sorry, at first glance I thought you had fixed the answer, so I deleted the comment. You need to add `x`, because the recursive sum should be adding up `y + 0 + 1 + ... + (x-1)`. Each recursive call gets a smaller value of `x`, so in the end you will add up `0 + 1 + ... + x`, not `x + x + ... x`.  If you add 1, you are just adding up `1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1`, `x` times.

Comment: @chepner, gotta.

Answer (score 1):

This is another  way to do this.

```
    def recurSum(x, y):
        return y if x < 1 else recurSum(x-1, x + y)
```

The expanded form of the above is:

```
    def recurSum(x, runningSum):
        if x < 1:
            return runningSum;
        else:
            return recurSum(x-1, x + runningSum)
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how did you come up with the rule?

Comment: Python does not have [Tail Call Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) but some other languages do. I wanted a solution which could leverage TCO and this is what I came up with.

Comment: It's tail-recursive, but it still doesn't leverage TCO, because as you said, Python doesn't *do* TCO.

Answer (score -1):

Does the function need to be recursive? I think you might be over complicating this a bit;

```
def sums(x,y):
    output = y + sum(range(0,x+1))
    return output
```

Here in one line you can add the values between 1 and x to y

Comment: This is not recursive.

Comment: While this is not a suitable problem for recursion in Python, it's still worth asking how the recursive solution would work.

Comment: Recursion seem like its over complicating it, so figured I'd throw out a non-recursion answer in case they were just trying to use recursion because they thought it was most suitable

Comment: That's something to confirm in the comments, not something to just assume.

Comment: Would've if I could've commented. Wasn't assuming, just asking a question